# VB.net Alternative way of ReDim Preserve

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, filestream, streamreader

my program does work but i think it suffers performance issues, it is consuming upto 40% of my total CPU usage while it is looping the array. normally my programs would only consume under 5% of CPU usage, i think ReDim Preserve is causing this as i am looping around 100,000+ of lines. here is my code.

```
    Dim sArray As String()
    Dim fStream As New System.IO.FileStream("messages.txt", IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim sReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fStream)
    Dim Index As Integer = 0
    Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
        ReDim Preserve sArray(Index)
        sArray(Index) = sReader.ReadLine
        Index += 1
    Loop

    fStream.Close()
    sReader.Close()
```

Is there any alternative way of placing values into an array aside from ReDim Preserve?
Thanks in advance, i am really trapped into this problem right now.

Here is now my updated code using List.

```
    Dim sArray As String()
    Dim sList As New List(Of String)
    Dim fStream As New System.IO.FileStream("messages.txt", IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim sReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fStream)
    Dim Index As Integer = 0
    Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
        sList.Add(sReader.ReadLine)
    Loop
    sArray = sList.ToArray

    fStream.Close()
    sReader.Close()
```

I still needed the funcionalities of an array so i created an array and placed the contents of the List into it.

Comment: In one of the answers it has been suggested that you use a List, which I agree with.  If for some reason you can't do that let us know.

Comment: i am having problems on where to start in converting it using List. a starting code could help

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a `List(Of String)`, which will leave room for future elements instead of resizing every time.

Answer (score 3):

As SLaks said best should be a List:

```
Dim sArray As New List(Of String)
Dim fStream As New System.IO.FileStream("messages.txt", IO.FileMode.Open)
Dim sReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fStream)
Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
    sArray.add(sReader.ReadLine)
Loop

fStream.Close()
sReader.Close()
```

Comment: thanks alot man this helped alot. i will post edit my code above with an updated one.

Comment: What funcionalities of an array do you need?

btw. you should accept SLaks answer, too ;)

Comment: Everything is done now, i am finally complete.

it really boosted the performance, my program can now read 100,000+ lines in just a second. thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are reading many lines might try replacing the end of stream test as well. Here is an alterative http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d(v=vs.80).aspx You might squeeze a few more milliseconds out of the process.

Answer (score 1):

Is seems like you are reading a file, an other option would be to use the [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File.ReadAllLines.aspx) method.

```
Dim sArray() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("messages.txt")
```